# Why I can't see CrmDiscoveryService type in Intellisense after adding web reference?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-4

I have added this CrmDiscoveryService Web service reference:

```
 http://<servername:port>/mscrmservices/2007/ad/crmdiscoveryservice.asmx?WSDL
```

But still cannot see CrmDiscoveryService type in Intellisense.

(I am working with CRM 4.0 and VS 2012 in C#.)

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your project after adding the web service reference ?

Comment: @Ondrej, yes, when I rebuild I get this error: The type or namespace name 'CrmDiscoveryService' does not exist in the namespace 'CrmSdk.Discovery' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check if file Reference.cs exists in the subfolder CrmDiscoveryService (should be under your project). Also try deleting the reference and re-adding it.

Comment: @Ondrej, CRM1 is the name of my project. CRM1\App_WebReferences\CrmDiscoveryService holds this only: Reference.svcmap and there's no Reference.cs

Comment: If you type that url directly into browser, do you get the wsdl markup ?

Comment: The problem is it isn't creating the Reference.cs class. You can try removing everything manually (both on the file system and in project itself) and re-adding it or adding the reference to brand new solution. If that doesn't help take a look WseWsdl2 tool - it can create proxy class which you're after from web service and the visual studio is using it internally. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms827743.aspx)

Comment: @Ondrej, WseWsdl2 returned me "Unauthorized" even I was connected via browser.

Comment: You said you're able to get the WSDL markup trough browser, right ? So you can download the WSDL markup trough browser, save it to the file and use WseWsdl2 over that saved file - for the proxy generation purpose it doesn't matter. Once the proxy will be created and referenced, you'll have to supply valid url (and possibly credentials) to the proxy instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a Service Reference, go to "Advanced"  In the first dialog window, then click "Add Web Reference" on the bottom of the page. On the next page you can add your web reference...